# Map ASP Membership User & Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model named 'Account' with a foreign key 'UserId' which maps to the aspnet_users table.

The Account model  also has as a navigation property 'Creator', the Creator model contains UserId, Username & Email.

What's the best way to map the values from aspnet_users to the Creator model?

I'd ideally like to be able to access this like: @Model.Creator.Username

I'm not looking to manipulate the membership system, I have a service that handles that. I'd just ideally like to map this object for read only purposes.

Comment: Please let me know if you figured out a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model which is not included in the context.

```
public class AccountContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Ignore<Creator>(); //Ignore map
    }

    public void FillCreatorToAccount(Account account)
    {
        var creator = Database.SqlQuery<Creator>("select UserId,UserName,Email from aspnet_users where UserId=@p0", account.UserId).SingleOrDefault();
        account.Creator = creator;
    }
}

public class Account
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public Creator Creator { get; set; }
}

public class Creator
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```